# Spring boot webflux mock server for Junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

How can we mock HTTP server response for writing junit test case ??

Spring boot - 2.1.3.RELEASE with netty server.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: 1.Wiremock , 2.mockserver  <!-- <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>  and 3.mockwebserver from okhttp

Comment: Can you show your junit test method / class?